# List of Known Issues needed for Eclipse Juno 4.2.1 IDE Platform

Tags: eclipse

Where can I get full release notes for Eclipse Juno 4.2.1 IDE platform?  More specifically, I'm looking for a list of known issues.

I've tried using the Bugzilla reporting interface, but did not get what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the [target milestones for Eclipse 4.2 SR1](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?bug_file_loc_type=allwordssubstr&bug_status=RESOLVED&bug_status=VERIFIED&bug_status=CLOSED&classification=Eclipse&classification=RT&columnlist=short_desc&keywords_type=allwords&long_desc_type=allwordssubstr&product=Equinox&product=JDT&product=PDE&product=Platform&query_format=advanced&remaction=&resolution=FIXED&short_desc=&short_desc_type=allwordssubstr&status_whiteboard=&status_whiteboard_type=allwordssubstr&target_milestone=4.2.1&type0-0-0=noop&value0-0-0=%7C&order=bug_id&query_based_on=) on the Bugzilla. I hope this may help you.

Comment: I think that should be sufficient for my needs.

Comment: For future reference, what search parameters did you use?  I see a bunch of stuff in the URL, but it would be nice to know what each parameters is for.